# Jquery plugin for Nested modal popup?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, modal-dialog

I need to do nested modal popup in my application. all popup's will have form submission, and comfirmation message modal dialog. Which plugin is easy to do this?. There will be an 3-4 level of nesting in there. Please help me to select the beset one.

thanks in advance.

Comment: A modal inside a modal..? Is that going to work from a UX point of view?

Comment: Modal on top of the another modal.

Comment: Ahhh. Makes sense now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never nested more than one lightbox within another but I tend to favour colorbox for my lightbox/popup needs.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

If you want a more conventional modal for your confirmation message you can use the jQuery UI one within the lightbox.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

One or both should give you what you need.

Comment: Both very good modals, I'd say use UI one if already using jQueryUI, but colorbox if not

Comment: How about JqModal? any drawback's?

Comment: Never used it so can't comment, have you tried the suggestions I gave above? Any reason why you're writing them off?

Comment: I tried to get nested popups working in colorbox, but since it appears to work off of unique IDs, I don't think it's possible. It looks like I'll be having to go with magnific for the base popups (since I already have them how I want) and colorbox or something else for the nested ones.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered recently bpopup JQuery plugin and it allows nested modal popups very very easy.

http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

Look for Example 6a in the previous url ;-)